# Changing Label provider of Jface tree viewer giving exceptions in MAC

Tags: java, macos, swt, jface

I am facing a critical issue using cell label provider for Jface tree viewer in MAC. In windows systems , there is no problem .
 I have a scenario for changing the label provider dynamically , for this first i have created
a tree viewer using  content provider and label provider(cell label provider).
After that i am trying to change the label provider of  the tree viewer using set Label Provider option , But i am getting null pointer exceptions.

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StyledCellLabelProvider.getViewerCell(StyledCellLabelProvider.java:230)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StyledCellLabelProvider.measure(StyledCellLabelProvider.java:258)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.OwnerDrawLabelProvider$OwnerDrawListener.handleEvent(OwnerDrawLabelProvider.java:56)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4188)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem.calculateWidth(TreeItem.java:280)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.setScrollWidth(Tree.java:2972)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem.setText(TreeItem.java:1473)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewerRow.setText(TreeViewerRow.java:116)a
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerCell.setText(ViewerCell.java:159)
```

Comment: I see you have added this to Eclipse Bugzilla, they will want a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi , i have provided the simplest example to produce the issue.